# Linking my Web Banner Image to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, slider, banner

I have created a web banner from scratch:

```
<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top"> <img id="adBanner1" src="http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/CommScope_Summer_Savings_front_page.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="804" height="300" /></a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var imgs1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/CommScope_Summer_Savings_front_page.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/PatchSee_excess_stock_promo.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/Dymo_XTL_Banner.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/The_Copper_Solution_-_Homepage.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Slider_Banners/Assynia_Patch_Cords_-_Up_to_50_off.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Slider_Banners/Product_Range_-_May_1.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Fluke_DTX_Buy_Back_2015.jpg");
var lnks1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/summer-savings","http://www.cmsplc.com/patchsee-stock-promo-2016","http://www.cmsplc.com/dymo-xtl-trade-in","http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/corning/corning-copper/corning-copper-solution.html","http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/assynia/assynia-copper-connectivity/assynia-patch-cords.html","http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/netscout.html","http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-networks-dtx-upgrade-offer");
var alt1 = new Array();
var currentAd1 = 0;
var imgCt1 = 7;
var intvl = 0;




function cycle1() {
  if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
    currentAd1 = 0;
  }
var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
  banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
  banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
  document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
  currentAd1++;
}

  intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);

  adBanner1.onmouseover = function () {
    clearInterval(intvl);
  }
  adBanner1.onmouseout = function () {
    intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
  }
// ]]></script>
```

The **first** image does not link through to a web page. All following images link perfectly. I believe I am missing something here:

```
<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top"> <img id="adBanner1" src="http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/CommScope_Summer_Savings_front_page.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="804" height="300" /></a></p>
```

Please advise as to how I can link this image to a URL page and ensure all images on my banner link properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U forgot to set href="http://www.cmsplc.com/summer-savings" for the  element in HTML that's why its not working for first Banner.Here is the modified code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <a id="adLink1" target="_top" href="http://www.cmsplc.com/summer-savings">
      <img id="adBanner1" src="http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/CommScope_Summer_Savings_front_page.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="804" height="300" />
    </a>
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var imgs1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/CommScope_Summer_Savings_front_page.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/PatchSee_excess_stock_promo.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/Dymo_XTL_Banner.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Homepage_Banners_NEW/The_Copper_Solution_-_Homepage.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Slider_Banners/Assynia_Patch_Cords_-_Up_to_50_off.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Slider_Banners/Product_Range_-_May_1.jpg", "http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Fluke_DTX_Buy_Back_2015.jpg");
    var lnks1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/summer-savings", "http://www.cmsplc.com/patchsee-stock-promo-2016", "http://www.cmsplc.com/dymo-xtl-trade-in", "http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/corning/corning-copper/corning-copper-solution.html", "http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/assynia/assynia-copper-connectivity/assynia-patch-cords.html", "http://www.cmsplc.com/brands/netscout.html", "http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-networks-dtx-upgrade-offer");
    var alt1 = new Array();
    var currentAd1 = 0;
    var imgCt1 = 7;
    var intvl = 0;




    function cycle1() {
      if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
        currentAd1 = 0;
      }
      var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
      var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
      banner1.src = imgs1[currentAd1]
      banner1.alt = alt1[currentAd1]
      document.getElementById('adLink1').href = lnks1[currentAd1]
      currentAd1++;
    }

    intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()", 4000);

    adBanner1.onmouseover = function() {
      clearInterval(intvl);
    }
    adBanner1.onmouseout = function() {
        intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()", 4000);
      }
      // ]]>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning you didn't set a href-attribute for the anchor, so the image is showing due to the static HTML, but the anchor misses the url. After the first cycle it is working correctly because then the url is set via the javascript.

So you have to change

`<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top">...`

to

`<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top" href="http://www.cmsplc.com/summer-savings">...`

Moreover your `window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);` is called in the wrong way. It should be `window.setInterval(cycle1,4000);`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8u3heye0/

Comment: Thanks very much! Very helpful!

Comment: Whilst youre around, is there any way I can add a scroll or buttons? @mxlse

Comment: Where you want to add this?